# Halved conducting spherical shell with uniform electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

I am troubling with physical reason of behavior. If I apply the uniform electric field on two halved conducting sphere shell, by calculation using stress tensor, I will get the force that is pulling these two apart.

[image: conducting sphere]

Can anyone help me to understand why it is happening physically?

**Calculation**

Here is the calculation from the class
[image]

Comment: Won't they be attracted due to polarization? I must be missing something.

Comment: That is what I thought, but math if i did not do mistake, it will pull apart. I will try to write the solution on the post

Comment: A minus (plus) charge will be induced on the southern (northern) hemisphere, the external field will therefore pull (push) that half to the south (north). What you say is also true but it turns out that the effect I mention is stronger.